# ALPN unsupported - error while consuming Google pub-sub messages in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp, alpn

We are developing a Spring Boot application which subscribed to a Google pub-sub topic. Below is my code -

**pom.xml which has GCP-Spring Boot related dependencies**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**application.yml file**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      project-id: project-dev
      credentials:
        location: file:C:/Users/project-dev.json
gcp:
  pubsub:
    subscription: dev-topic-sub
```

**Configuration class to define beans**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.integration.AckMode;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.integration.inbound.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

@Configuration
public class GCPPubSubConfig {

    @Value("${gcp.pubsub.subscription}")
    private String subscriptionId;

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("gcpChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel, PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, subscriptionId);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO);
        adapter.setPayloadType(String.class);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel gcpChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
}
```

**This is my listener class**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class GCPPubSubSubscriber {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "gcpChannel")
    public void messageReceiver(String payload) {

        log.info(payload);
    }
}
```

Where the above code worked fine for me in my local system. I am able to start my application, subscribe to the channel, listen to the messages in my ServiceActivator method and able to print them.

**When I deploy them to Azure cloud, able to subscribe to the channel, started the application but while listening to the message, getting the below exception**

```
08:10:42.213  INFO [,,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8085 (http) with context path ''
 08:10:42.233  INFO [,,,] 1 --- [           main] .a.e.t.d.t.b.Application : Started Application in 49.345 seconds (JVM running for 52.997)
 08:10:43.098 ERROR [,,,] 1 --- [bscriber-SE-1-4] c.g.c.p.v.StreamingSubscriberConnection  : terminated streaming with exception

com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:47) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$1.onFailure(StreamingSubscriberConnection.java:238) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.101.0.jar!/:1.101.0]
        at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) [api-common-1.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1083) [guava-29.0-jre.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) [guava-29.0-jre.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1174) [guava-29.0-jre.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:969) [guava-29.0-jre.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:760) [guava-29.0-jre.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture$InternalSettableFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:95) [api-common-1.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:77) [api-common-1.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.api.core.SettableApiFuture.setException(SettableApiFuture.java:52) [api-common-1.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$StreamingPullResponseObserver.onError(StreamingSubscriberConnection.java:174) [google-cloud-pubsub-1.101.0.jar!/:1.101.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedResponseObserver.onError(TracedResponseObserver.java:103) [gax-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onErrorImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:84) [gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.StateCheckingResponseObserver.onError(StateCheckingResponseObserver.java:86) [gax-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onClose(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:149) [gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426) [grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66) [grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689) [grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577) [grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751) [grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740) [grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) [grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) [grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_275]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_275]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_275]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_275]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_275]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_275]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_275]
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:47) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onErrorImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:82) [gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar!/:1.49.1]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
        at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-api-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler.handlerAdded() has thrown an exception; removed.
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:624) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.replace(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:572) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.replace(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:515) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ProtocolNegotiationHandler.fireProtocolNegotiationEvent(ProtocolNegotiators.java:767) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$WaitUntilActiveHandler.channelActive(ProtocolNegotiators.java:676) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:216) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:209) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1398) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:216) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractEpollChannel.java:620) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:653) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:529) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:465) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ALPN unsupported. Is your classpath configured correctly? For Conscrypt, add the appropriate Conscrypt JAR to classpath and set the security provider. For Jetty-ALPN, see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-starting
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator$FailureWrapper.wrapSslEngine(JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator.java:122) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.configureAndWrapEngine(JdkSslContext.java:360) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.newEngine(JdkSslContext.java:335) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler.handlerAdded0(ProtocolNegotiators.java:348) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ProtocolNegotiationHandler.handlerAdded(ProtocolNegotiators.java:726) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:971) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

As per the exception I suspected that there might be an issue with Java version hence checked the details

Java version details in my local system -

```
Desktop>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

Java version details in Azure  -

```
/home/aksuser $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.17.1) (Alpine 8.275.01-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
/home/aksuser $
```

Is there any chance that the issue is with the Java version? as it is working fine in local but not in Azure. Why ALPN comes into picture when working with GCP? If the issue is with Java version that doesn't support ALPN then what are the possibilities to resolve the error?

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the ALPN supported Java version need to be installed to make this work. As you have deployed your application in a container based environment please try customizing your application alone with the ALPN supported JDK image so that the other applications in the environment is not interrupted.

you can check if your java version is GCP compatible or not from this link -

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/main/google-cloud-util/google-cloud-compat-checker

Answer (score 2):

gRPC is using Netty for SSL.

According to the official Documentation for gRPC:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#netty

> **Transport Security (TLS)**
>
> HTTP/2 over TLS mandates the use of ALPN to negotiate the use of the
> h2 protocol and support for the GCM mode of AES.

They are both Java 8, but it seems that the Alpine version is not supporting ALPN.  That is what the error is stating.

It seems that ALPN support was backported to Java 8u252 and Java 9.

You could **either** do the below, or change your Azure Java image to a version that supports ALPN.

**Changes for applications indirectly using ALPN**

> Applications that are using Java 8 and that depend on libraries that
> provide ALPN support (such as the jetty-alpn-openjdk8-[client|server]
> artifact described above) must modify the way they are started.
>
> For an application that is still using an OpenJDK version prior to
> 8u252, the typical command line requires the alpn-boot jar in the
> bootclasspath and a library that uses the Jetty ALPN APIs (here as an
> example, jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server) in the classpath:

```
/opt/openjdk-8u242/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/alpn-boot-8.1.13.v20181017.jar -classpath jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server-9.4.27.v20200227:...
```

> For the same application that wants to use OpenJDK 8u252 or later, the
> command line becomes:

```
/opt/openjdk-8u252/bin/java -classpath jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server-9.4.28.v20200408:...
```

> That is, the -Xbootclasspath option must be removed and the library
> must be upgraded to a version that supports the backported OpenJDK
> ALPN APIs.

Further Information regarding this : https://webtide.com/jetty-alpn-java-8u252/

Comment: How to actually implement this in my Spring Boot application?  I have tried adding the mentioned `jetty-alpn` jars as dependencies in my application pom.xml which didn't actually work out.

Comment: Please read this @AdarshRoop https://hoogvliet.de/http2-and-spring-boot